# Grub menu problem

Tags: 14.04

- I'm using ubuntu alongside windows 8.1.
- because of some problems i'll have to setup windows again
- but after installing windows the ubuntu grub menu will disappear.
- is there any easy way to bring it back without "EasyBCD" software?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , there is.

1)Boot with a Live Ubuntu Disk/CD

2)Type the following command in terminal to install and start Boot-Repair.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-   trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

3)Select the recommended repair ,It will take few minutes and after your next reboot , you will be greeted with sweat GRUB menu.

Comment: Do i need internet connection for this action? 
What do u mean by "sweat grub menu"?

Comment: Yes , you will need internet connection.That just means you will have grub menu.